# Ruby : cannot load such file -- google/apis/drive_v3 (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, bitrise

I am using ruby to write a script for downloading resources from google drive.

This script is running successfully locally, but while running on Bitrise it gives the following error;

```
ruby config_downloader.rb -f Android -p 550 -g ''
/Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- google/apis/drive_v3 (LoadError)
    from /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from config_downloader.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is my Gemfile;

```
# Autogenerated by fastlane
#
# Ensure this file is checked in to source control!

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'fastlane'
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'google-apis-drive_v3'

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

Comment: Please don't upload code as images. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: What's the content of `config_downloader.rb` ? Also, can you please share the whole Bitrise config (bitrise.yml)?

Answer (score 1):

After playing around for a while, I've got the issue which was missing gem file in the Bitrise config file called "bitrise.yml".

By adding the missing gem via "sudo gem install google-apis-drive_v3", the issue is resolved.

Thanks for the support!!!

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue :) Happy building!